# One room is always the hottest in the house

Tags: air-conditioning, ceiling-fan, central-air, temperature

Whether it's winter or summer, hot or cold outside, my bedroom is always the hottest in the house. I have taken temperature readings and the air temperature can exceed 85 degrees. I have a fan almost always running. I open my vent when the AC is running and close it when the heater is running. No matter what I do, my room is always 80+ degrees.

What can I do to make my room a comfortable temperature? The door is sometimes open, sometimes closed. I have an air intake directly outside my room.

Comment: How is house heated/cooled?  If using ducts, can tune the ducts so less heat more cool goes to the room.  Blocking sunlight coming though window/s can help cool the room.  Where is the room in house, single floor house or multi floor house?  Upper rooms tend to be warmer, heat rises.

Comment: My room is on the top floor of a 3 story house (but really more like 2 1/2 floor, as the basement is partly underground). The house is heated and cooled by a central air handler in the basement with two dampers for the basement and for the top two floors. I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's a 5 ton system. The room is on an outside corner.

Comment: What area of the world are you?  Winter in Maine vs Winter in Florida are very different.

Comment: I am in Maryland.

Comment: This will be tricky to determine without a model/floor plan of the house, showing the layout of the duct work. Proper HVAC technicians do Manual J, S, and T calculations before they start on Manual D, which is the duct work design, when installing an HVAC system for the house. For a *three story* house it will be quite complex (and your options will be very limited).

Comment: Ducts in floor of middle floor serve the middle and basement. Two vertical air shafts - one for supply, the other for return. Large horizontal duct coming off of it into the basement ceiling / middle floor floor, and the shaft continues upward where it branches off in the attic to serve rooms from above. Return air goes into an intake on each floor (in-wall on basement and middle, in-ceiling on top floor) and one in the master bedroom (directly connected to the return shaft, loud.)

Comment: Do you get good air flow when the AC is on? Our son's room is upstairs, and despite the vent, he gets almost zero airflow through it, therefore it's hot in the summer and cold in the winter. That's on the list of things to fix when our HVAC guy is here next... Also, what is directly _below_ your bathroom? If it's the kitchen, maybe you're getting hot air coming up the stove vent heating the bathroom all year round.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/236936/how-do-i-fix-a-loud-intake-vent   Related.   Same house

Comment: Yes, same house. Looking for a solution to both problems.