# How do I fix a loud intake vent?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, ducts, central-air, noise-reduction

In the master bedroom, there is one of four intake vents in the house, and this particular one is very loud.

Our house has two vertical air shafts that run parallel to each other, one for supply and one for return. The intake in the master bedroom is connected directly to the return shaft - no duct between it and the shaft. Directly behind the vent is a 3-story drop straight down into the air handler.

I have held a piece of paper next to the offending intake and the paper gets drawn strongly against it.

I tried this on the middle floor as well, as its intake is the largest but still right on the return shaft. Similar effect, but not quite as strong. This vent is also somewhat loud, but not as loud as the master bedroom one.

I then tried the paper on the intake directly outside my room, which has a long duct connecting it to the return shaft. Not nearly as much suction as the one in the master bedroom.

I did the same thing on the basement return, which is the smallest of them all. That one had more suction than the top floor hallway one, but nowhere near as much as the middle or master bedroom intakes.

Vent sizes:

Basement: roughly 14x14 inches, estimated 10 feet of duct that is 8-10 inches wide, connects to bottom of return air shaft. [image: Basement vent]

Middle floor: roughly 18x18 inches, directly on return air shaft. [image: Middle floor vent]

Top floor - hallway: roughly 18x18 inches, estimated 20 feet of duct that is 14 inches wide, connects to top of return shaft. [image: Hallway vent]

Top floor - master bedroom: roughly 14x14 inches, directly on return air shaft. The problematic one. [image: Room vent]

Here's where the two vertical shafts connect to the air handler in the basement:
[image: Air handler]

The two shafts are more visible here:
[image: Air shafts]

How can I make the vent quieter? Also, how can I give the one in the hallway more suction?

Here's a *not very professionally* made diagram of what the vents are like:
[image: Diagram]

EDIT: The sound is an air rushing sound, not whistling or any other noise. Either that or it could be the sound of the fan.

Comment: What is the cfm of the fan. Can you get us pictures of how the three return air ducts are attached to the air handler?

Comment: All four are attached to the main vertical shaft. It is a roughly 20x24 inch duct that goes from the basement to the attic. This connects via a right angle and goes directly into the air handler, in the basement. I'm not sure the CFM, but the system is a 4 ton system. Two intakes are directly connected to the shaft, and the other two are connected via short duct sections. There is only one air shaft serving all four returns. Similarly, there is a supply shaft that runs parallel to the return air duct.

Comment: You prob have 1600 cfm    so the three RA vents total 807 square inches which is appropriate. Are each of the RAvents filtered?  Or does the unit pull all that air through a single filter at the air handler?

Comment: The air handler has a single filter in the path of the return air. There are four vents, but one was easily overlookable. Edited the post to make it more easily readable.

Comment: What size is the filter?. If you remove the filter does the noise level change?

Comment: What is the diameter of the return air trunk?

Comment: Noise level gets slightly louder when the filter is removed. The duct going up is roughly 20x24 inches. What is the return air trunk? The circular duct at the top? That is about 12 inches.

Comment: Added images now @Kris

Comment: The trunk is the main duct going from AH to 3rd floor.

Comment: Regardless the size of grilles you have a small opening in #1 photo. That room not pulling much air

Comment: Filter size?. 1600 cfm needs a big filter  removing your filter allows more air to flow thus more noise.  I have a feeling if yiu enlarged the hole in shaft in image #1 there would be a drop in turbulence at master bedroom intake. Remove all grilles and calculate the actual total square inches of the holes that are behind them.

Comment: The filter is 1x18x24 inches and sits directly in the path of return air going into the air handler. There is a large metal fin next to where the filter goes, you can see it in the image of the AH.

Comment: Well the filter is adequately sized.  There is a caution about vents being too close to the end of a trunk on supply side.  It can cause imbalance of air flow since the trunk does not pressurize like a plenum should But acts more like a chimney.    The same imbalance may be occurring with intake attached to the end of this shaft.       Am I  Understanding  that the loud Ke is the one attached to the top of the shaft?

Comment: https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/rooms-not-getting-enough-air-this-duct-design-flaw-may-be-to-blame/     This kind of addresses that thought

Comment: Yes, the loud one is directly attached to the top of the shaft (no ducting whatsoever, just a hole cut in the wall with the shaft right behind it.

Comment: Added a diagram of the system (return side only)

Comment: Could it be you have a greater pressure differential in the bedroom due to the air being blown into the room and adjacent areas (and perhaps configuration drag of the environment matters, too, like furniture and closed doors)? Courtesy note: I would rephrase this as a comment to Lee Sam's answer, since it is already addressing conservation of mass flow, but I don't have the privileges to post a comment. (I don't get why this site is setup that way, but I am sure there is a reason.)

Answer (score 1):

In this case “size matters”. (Sorry, but I couldn’t wait to use that phrase.)

Your 4 ton unit pushes a certain amount of air to various spaces. Therefore, that air must come from somewhere, so the unit will draw sufficient air through the existing ductwork.

If the existing ductwork is sufficient size it will easily draw a sufficient amount of air. If the existing ductwork is too small, it will draw air extra fast through the ductwork causing a “whistling” sound. This size and sound can be calculated.  However, as a rule of thumb, the return air should add up to be about the same size as the supply air size ductwork.

There are many factors that go into determining the size of the return air ductwork, including number of elbows, register sizes, inline filters, etc. However, be aware it’s based on ductwork from the unit all the way to the registers.